# Getting used ID generated by IdGeneratorStrategy after shutting down system

Tags: gwt, jakarta-ee, constraints, derby, id-generation

I'm working on a web app with GWT running on an embedded Winstone server and I'm using Derby as database with a persistence manager.
I'm generating a persistent class with a Long ID, which is generated by the `IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY`.
The problem is, when I shut down my application the `IdGeneratorStrategy` tries to create a object of this class with the same id, because it doesn't know that in the database is the same id already given to another object, which causes an error saying that two constraints have the same set of columns.

So I need to be able to tell the `IdGenerator` to get the latest Id and create a different new one.

Is it possible with this Generator?

Or do I need to save the Ids in a table within the database and always take the last Id and generate it "by hand"?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is mostly about GWT, but wanted to mention that Derby supports generated identity columns: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefsqlj37836.html#rrefsqlj37836